# Django url template tag with variable

Tags: django

In my urls.py I have something along these lines

```
 # Dont use repeating patterns when only the end changes.
 url(r'^products/', include(patterns('foo.apps.bar.views',
    url(r'^$', 'product_family', name='products'),
    url(r'^(?P<page>[\w-]+)$', 'product_single'),
    ...
 ))),
```

Which would equate to:

www.demo.com/products/ - take you to a page where we see all products
www.demo.com/products/alpha - take you to the alpha product page -
*if alpha does not exist it redirects to the products page*

I can link to these pages via the specified 'name' in urls.py

```
<a href="{% url 'products' %}">Products</a>
```

How can I do the same but supply it with a variable to take me to product_single?

```
<a href="{% url 'products/{{ products.slug }}' %}">Products</a>
```

I know I could just write out the link without the url tag but was curious if there was syntax to use it like the a href above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your single product url a name.

```
url(
    r'^products/',
    include(
        patterns('foo.apps.bar.views',
            url(r'^$', 'product_family', name='products'),
            url(r'^(?P<page>[\w-]+)$', name='product_single'),
        )
    )
),
```

Pass the `slug` to the newly named url.

```
<a href="{% url 'product_single' products.slug %}">Products</a>
{# OR #}
<a href="{% url 'product_single' page=products.slug %}">Products</a>
```

Comment: Doh! I knew it would be something like that, looks clean too. Much appreciated sir! Will accept in a couple min.